# os.system() calls to mpirun don't work after calling a script with python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to run mpirun on a python code that has already been run via console, a jupyter notebook or from Pycharm's console. All the code run goes fine until the call to the mpirun process, which completely skips.

I have created two codes, `parallel.py`, which contains the actions to be done by mpirun; and `coder.py`, which calls `parallel.py`. When running `coder.py`, all the key steps are run, except the call to `parallel.py`. When running `parallel.py` alone, the code runs normally.

`parallel.py`

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
print('RANK %s'%comm.rank)
```

`coder.py`

```py
import os, sys
syspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

print('Running code')
com = 'mpirun -v -np 3 ' + str(sys.executable) + " -m mpi4py " + syspath + "/parallel.py"
os.system(com)
print('Done')
```

After calling `python coder.py`:

### EXPECTED

```py
Running code
RANK 1
RANK 0
RANK 2
Done
```

### OBSERVED

```
Running code
Done
```

After calling `python parallel.py`:

```
RANK 1
RANK 0
RANK 2
```

I guess that by calling `os.system` after `python` the process is already "blocked" and `os.system` is unable to call `mpirun` because of this "blocking".

If this is like that, is there any way to circumvent this option?

Comment: What if you use the absolute path to `mpirun`?

Comment: I guess you meant "After calling python coder.py" instead of "parallel.py"

Comment: Calling with absolute path does not work either. However, if I only run `os.system(mpirun --version)` it gives me the version, so I don't think the problem is on this side.

Comment: you can try printing `com` before calling `os.system()`. Since your program displays `Done`, it means `os.system(com)` is executed and returns.

Comment: Printing `com` does nothing. And the program displays `Done` of course because it executed, but execution returned nothing, which is the point I am trying to solve here.

Comment: does `print(com)` print nothing at all ? if not, what if you copy/paste the command line ? what if you `os.system('echo hello')` ? does it print something ?

Comment: you can also try `os.system('mpirun hostname')` and see how things go

Comment: All the printing commands go right. Even running mpirun without nothing goes well. The problem is running mpirun with a task; that's when it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

On my environment (Python 2.7, MPI4Py 3.0.1 and MPICH 3.2.1), the following code works as you expect:

```
import os
import sys
syspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

print('Running code')
com = 'mpirun -np 3 ' + str(sys.executable) + " " + syspath + "/parallel.py"
print(com)
os.system(com)
print('Done')
```

It seems that you don't need to provide the module mpi4py in the command line as you import it in the parallel.py file. Also, I have removed the -v option which adds a lot of verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

I continued the thread [here](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6773). After some recommendations we realised that mpi4py was compiled for a previous version of mpi.

I uninstalled everything (any possible mpirun version on the computer) and, just in case, reinstalled my conda packages in a clean environment. Everything works fine now.